# How to force Eclipse to update methods' visibility

Tags: eclipse

I have some projects in my Eclipse (indigo) and in one of them, I've changed the visibility of a class method inside a package, but the compiler still showing an error message informing that the method is not visible, when I try to access it from another package, through "import".

I even restarted Eclipse, but the error persists. When I run an acces to this method in server, catalina raises an error saying the same.

What's going on? Why my method properties dont update? There's some tricky thing to do, beyond declare public a method inside a public class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do a clean and/or build all?

You should check that what is deployed corresponds to your new code, in target folder in general, but if it is deployed on Tomcat it could be another folder. You may delete the content in this folder, rebuild and check that the new built content is in this folder.

Comment: Did you try to remove the deployed files?

Comment: Yeap. I'm suspecting that would be errors in the code which are not showed and, in some way, are blocking the updates;

Comment: it's a bit radical, but you could commit and checkout somewhere else to see if the issue persists and if it is due to your env.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the problem is coused by a compiler error. You may remove all your compiled class-files and run a build again. Another problem is the filesystem synchronization in eclipse. A refresh on project folder can resolve this!